# Slim 3.3 missing characters in output

Tags: response, php-5.5, slim-3

I'm trying to get Slim to run on my Windows 7 system.
So far I've gotten everything installed with Composer but when I run a very simple program, the output is not as intended.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Slim\App;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App;

$app->get('/', function (Request $in, Response $out, $args) {
 return $out->write("xxxxx");
});

$app->run();
```

I am expecting output "xxxxx", instead i get "x".

This means I loose 4 characters somewhere.
Running PHP 5.5.12
The encoding is UTF-8 (not BOM)

When i run 
    "curl -v http://localhost:8080/"

I get

```
D:\wamp\www\slim_test\src\public>curl -v http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Host: localhost:8080
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 5
<

x* Closing connection 0
```

I'd appreciate your help.

**EDIT**
Once i append these lines of code to the end of the file, the response is correct.

```
$response = $app->run(true); //Silent mode, wont send the response
$response = $response->withoutHeader("Content-Length"); //Remove the Content-Length

$app->respond($response); //Now we send the response
```

I cannot figure out why.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved as I found a very stupid mistake.

I had 2 blank spaces before the `<?php` tag.